# making a detox smoothie more palatable

Tags: flavor

I currently make a detox smoothie with the following ingredients: 1 orange, 1 banana, 2 cups frozen wild blueberries, 1 c cilantro, 1 tsp barley juice grass powder, 1 tsp spirulina, tbsp or Atlantic sea dulse.

It tastes like a dirty fish tank.

I can make something separate with all the stuff that doesn't taste good to me. (everything but the fruit and cilantro)
I like cilantro but not in my fruit, so I can put cilantro in a salad but all the other stuff is beyond horrible to me.

Is there any gluten, egg and dairy-free way to make the barley juice grass powder, 1 tsp spirulina, and tbsp of Atlantic sea dulse more palatable?  Saying it's an acquired taste won't help.

I'm 2 years into trying to use this stuff.

Comment: you're mixing seaweed, orange, cilantro and grass? no wonder it tastes bad. Are you sure you're using fresh ingredients? Do you drink it right after you make? Have you tried sugar (or perhaps salt?), maybe some spices? What have you tried in 2 years?

Comment: Hi, I would like to remind everybody that health discussion is off topic, in answers or in comments. The mention of the origin of the recipe is to be treated as irrelevant background information, and we cannot share our opinions on the health properties of either the original version, or any changed version that may get suggested.

Comment: Suggestion: split it into 2 smoothies.  A small one with the herbs etc. and just enough liquid (orange juice, maybe some water, aim for not sweet) that you can down it quickly, then have the rest of the fruit to take the taste away

Comment: And perhaps blend a whole chilli into the herbal (for want of a better name) part, or at least grind plenty of black pepper in there

Comment: Luciano, thank you for trying to be helpful.  I have tried separating out the good tasting fruit and consuming all the other stuff separately but that is so bad I just won't stick with it.  I can eat all the ingredients separately as long as I get them all in within a 24 hour period so I tried using the cilantro in salads which eliminates that from making the mix worse but it isn't enough becuse the other stuff makes the fruit taste bad enough that I don't want to eat the fruit.   I tried making salad dressings out of spirulina, barley juice powder, dulse, honey,  it was awful.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you can use "@" to ping and reply to the user (like @jean). Otherwise, they won't be notified and thus may not notice your comments.

Comment: @jean you can use the little grey flag button to the left of the comment to flag it for moderator attention. We have a code of conduct (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/conduct), and criticizing a poster's choice of food is indeed considered unwanted. I removed the comments related to that part now.

Comment: The 'nasty' tasting stuff is in small quantities. If its going to taste nasty anyway.... just down the 3 powders in some way, then chase it with the smoothie to mask the aftertaste?

Answer (score 6):

**Gelatin capsule.**

[image: gelatin capsules]

You can buy empty gelatin capsules for endeavors like this.  Put the seaweed powders in the gelatin capsule(s).  You will not taste them.  Wash the capsules down with the fruit smoothie.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround. For the specific case, it may not be very practicable - I suppose one capsule won't take more than 1 ml of volume, and OP has to take 1 tsp (5 ml) of the spirulina and 1 tbsp (15 ml) of the other ingredient, making it 20 capsules daily. Maybe there are producers who sell larger ones, but the size is limited by the human gag reflex.